# Are there any tools for Windows that will point out unseen issues related to starting after putting your laptop into sleep or hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

It seems to me that my laptop runs slower after I've started it up again after putting it to sleep or making it hibernate.

Are there any tools that will analyze unseen problems that bringing your machine back from one of these states might cause?

Comment: Rather than "seems" can you run some kind of test that will give an objective metric saying that it is slower?

Comment: @soandos Good point...alot of times I suppose by the time I leave and hibernate or sleep I have too many tabs open, but closing them doesn't seem remedy this.  Could you suggest a test that I could run?

Comment: Just one of many tools, http://novabench.com/